# Flutter Web with Navigation 2 - control browser back button

Tags: browser, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I tried this:

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    return false;
  },
  child: Scaffold(...
```

and I also use this:

```
setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());
```

The `onWillPop` is not called when clicking the browser's back button.